# Draw Photoshop brush using Actionscript (in Flash)

Tags: actionscript, photoshop

I would like to draw a Photoshop brush (.abr) in Flash using Actionscript 3.0
Is any documentation or references for the .abr Format available? Anybody tried this?

Answer (score 0):

i found nothing regarding .abr files in flash but this: [AS3 photoshop brushes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616902/as3-photoshop-brushes)

so you have to write your own routines like they did on aviary.com or pixlr.com and so on

you could try to read the .abr file

Comment: Any hint how to do this? I want to read brush shapes from file. I thought about storing the shape.graphics methods to file and using some sort of "eval()" function to execute the code. However, Actionscript 3 does not allow this. Any hint how this could work?